# Specifying range in RandomReal

Tags: list-manipulation, random

Is it possible to define the specific range of a `RandomReal` array for each coordinate? For example, the code

```
x = 1; y = 10; L = 20;
{RandomReal[x, L], RandomReal[y, L]} // Transpose
```

Gives me a list of 20 pairs where the first coordinate is a random real between 0 and 1, and the second is a random real between 0 and 10.

I suspect there is a neater way of writing this. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is. You can use RandomPoint and Rectangle but it is not really any more concise.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One can come up with variations on your version, but I don't think they're really better. E.g. `Transpose[{1, 10} RandomReal[1, {2, 20}]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with `RandomReal` that I know of, but you can define a `UniformDistribution` with your required limits and draw samples from it using `RandomVariate`:

```
pts = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 10}}], 20]
```

Check that it works as expected:

```
MinMax /@ Transpose@pts
```

> `{{0.00103093, 0.996982}, {0.530043, 9.94596}}`

Answer (score 4):

Just marginally faster

```
x = 1; y = 10; L = 20;
Transpose[{RandomReal[x, L], RandomReal[y, L]}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {4.2*10^-6,Null}

```
ReIm@RandomComplex[{0, x + I y}, L]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {2.5*10^-6,Null}

Answer (score 1):

Marco's solution is the best way to do this. An alternative procedure is to use `RescalingTransform[]` on `RandomReal[]`, like so:

```
RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}][RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]]
```